# Random selecting 20% between a time frame

Tags: r, random, sampling, duration

I have a lot of recordings to analyze but not enough time to go through the whole of each recording. So now what I would like to do in R is to put a CSV document in there. With the filename and the duration of the recording. As example:

[image]

Now what I would like R to do is randomly select 20 % of the duration for each file. And then put these numbers in a new table with the file name. Is this possible to do in R?

Comment: Hey, Thank you for asking the question. The SO community will be more helpful if you can describe in detail what you are trying to do via code snippets preferably and what is the exact problem you are facing. This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly; first we convert the total length to a duration object; after that we calculate the 20% of the length; then we use the random sample from a uniform distribution (`runif` function) to select a place to start, which should be somewhere between the start and the end minus sample size,

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

foo = tibble(duration = c("00:22:11", "00:00:48", "00:25:00"))

foo %>% mutate(recording_duration = duration(as.duration(hms(duration)))) %>%
  mutate(sample_size = recording_duration*.2) %>%
  mutate(random_sample_start = runif(1)*(recording_duration-sample_size)) %>%
  mutate(random_sample_start_hms = seconds_to_period(random_sample_start)) %>%
  mutate(random_sample_end = seconds_to_period(random_sample_start + sample_size )) %>%
  select(duration, random_sample_start_hms, random_sample_end, sample_size)
```

and it looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  duration random_sample_start_hms random_sample_end     sample_size           
  <chr>    <Period>                <Period>              <Duration>            
1 00:22:11 17M 22.8747033467516S   21M 49.0747033467517S 266.2s (~4.44 minutes)
2 00:00:48 37.6093056052923S       47.2093056052923S     9.6s                  
3 00:25:00 19M 35.290800165385S    24M 35.290800165385S  300s (~5 minutes)
```